# iOS, show specific html content from site on web view

Tags: html, ios, parsing

I would like to retrieve the data from a specific part of the html of a site, and I wrote the following code.  Unfortunately, the code is not working.  How can I fix this?

the html class name is "topic_content", and every article in applicable site contains it (see the comments in code).

```
@implementation DetailViewController
....
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
      .....
      activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
      [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
      ....
      [self callDetailNews];
}

-(void)callDetailNews{
      ....
      if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]!=NotReachable)
      {
           // article link :: http://el3en.com/?articles=topic&topic=20840 (token_ID)

           // <td class="topic_content" colspan='6' itemprop="articleBody"  style="text-align:justify;  word-wrap: break-word; width:100%">

           // NSString *someHTML = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].innerHTML;"];

           NSString *articleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://el3en.com/?articles=topic&topic=%@",token_ID];

           NSURL *articleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:articleString];
           NSError *error;
           NSString *articlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:articleURL
                                                 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&error];

           [_webView loadHTMLString:articlePage baseURL:nil];

           //NSString *someHTML = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('topic_content')[0].innerHTML;"];
           //NSLog(@"Content : %@",someHTML);
     }
     .....
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [activityIndicator startAnimating];
     self.webView.hidden=true;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
     [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('topic_content')[0].sinnerHTML;"];

     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
     self.webView.hidden=false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  How is it not working?  Do you get an error message?  Stack Overflow is a place to go after you have done your best to solve the problem.  We want to see what you've tried, what has worked, and what sorts of outputs you get.  There are a billion ways for something to "not work," and we need to know what specifically is going wrong.

Comment: the code don't throw any error, the code don't work mean don't show the content from site.

Comment: Does it show anything?  Or is it just blank?  If you NSLog the article string, do you get something in your logs?  Maybe you just didn't hook up your web view correctly.

Comment: the app load every time and don't stop then the code didn't show anything

Answer (score 2):

You should use innerHtml instead sinnerHtml, besides this you need to get the string and load this string into another webview. Pls see example

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *fakeView;
@end

@implementation ViewController


UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];



    [self callDetailNews];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)callDetailNews{

    if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]!=NotReachable)
    {
        // article link :: http://el3en.com/?articles=topic&topic=20840 (token_ID)

        // <td class="topic_content" colspan='6' itemprop="articleBody"  style="text-align:justify;  word-wrap: break-word; width:100%">

        // NSString *someHTML = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].innerHTML;"];

        NSString *articleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://el3en.com/?articles=topic&topic=%@",@"20840"];

        NSURL *articleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:articleString];
        NSError *error;
        NSString *articlePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:articleURL
                                                         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                            error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Request %@",articleURL);
    self.fakeView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        self.fakeView.delegate = self;
        [self.fakeView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:articleURL]];

        //NSString *someHTML = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('topic_content')[0].innerHTML;"];
        //NSLog(@"Content : %@",someHTML);
    }

}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    self.webView.hidden=true;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error %@" ,[error description]);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    if(webView == self.fakeView) {
        NSString* javascriptString = [self.fakeView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('topic_content')[0].innerHTML"];

        NSLog(@"%@",javascriptString);
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:javascriptString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
        self.fakeView = nil;
    }else{
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.webView.hidden=false;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: haha "sinnerHtml" sounds like an awesome class, but yeah "inner" is definitely more useful!

Comment: just edited my answer since was an error in the callback

Comment: sorry, this code doesn't work, the exception occurred, this the image show that http://postimg.org/image/i41lcfhbr/ can you help me by tutorial to work this from zero or beginning :)

Comment: just updated the code working, I've tried in my local and it works